# Snow leopard server: use a NAS volume as share point

Tags: network, sharing, osx-server, nas

I have a mounted nas volume (/Volumes/Volume_1) and i would like to create a share point on this, so that it can be accessed via FTP or whatever.

Yet, when in server admin > file sharing, I cannot see this volume.

Is there anything I can do to see my NAS volume?

PS: that's a shame, I wanted to tag my post snow-leopard-server... because I thought it made sense... but it's not possible until I earn these 150 reputations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X Server does allow the resharing of AFP mounts but not SMB/CIFS mounts. You can however get around it by using a symlink (`ln -s /Volumes/Volume_1 /SOME/PATH`) and share `/SOME/PATH`. While both options allow it to work it's not recommended (permissions, resource fork handling, max file size, etc. may cause hard to debug issues).

Alternatively on the command line you can use `sharing` (eg. `sudo sharing -a path -s shareflags`)

Comment: +1 for your trick, but do you know why apple just let resharing AFP? or do you have any link?

Comment: @Amirr3zA: I'm not sure why - it's not in the documentation either. To be honest I was expecting to not be able to

Comment: Thanks. I actually decided to take another option: mount my NAS as a NFS share, which appears then automatically in the list of volumes.